# Почему на разных компьютерах разная скорость парсинга?

Tags: парсер

Занимаюсь парсингом одного сайта, написал программу на питоне, запустил на двух компьютерах сразу. Программа одна и та же, сайт один и тот же, интернет один и тот же по кабелям, впн нет. Но на одном компьютере скорость 30 страниц в секунду, на другом 8 страниц в секунду (считал отдельно). При этом первый компьютер стоит 70к, а второй - 250к, вычислительные мощности просто несравнимые, но при этом первый нагружает процессор на 20%, а второй на все 100%. Програмная часть полностью одинаковая, Windows был целиком клонирован с первого компьютера на второй. Может быть вы знаете, почему скорость парсинга так сильно отличается?

Comment: Может на втором антивирус все соединения проверяет? )  Точно всё одинаковое? Кстати, зря, что Windows клонированный. Если железо разное, то и драйвера должны быть разные. Может с драйверами что. Провайдер то всё-таки разный? Провайдер тоже может влиять.

Comment: Проверил сейчас, бранмауэр не при чём. Одинаковое, причём для обоих компьютеров ос не родная, с третьего компьютера клонирована. Драйвера все ставил актуальные, но сейчас перепроверю. Оба компьютера в один модем воткнуты.

Comment: А, даже вот так... Ну, всё-таки цена - не всегда показатель, лучше конкретную конфигурацию железа обоих компов в вопросе написать, если это не секретная инфа. Ну и потестить бы какими-то бенчмарками оба компа. Может вылезет во что там упирается в железе.

Comment: Бенчмарками тестил, разница в 4 раза. 
https://ibb.co/F6BR0rn
https://ibb.co/KLgB5r5
Это нагрузка при работе программы на скринах

Comment: Без характеристик обоих компьютеров судить трудно. Вариантов может быть миллион - от того, что на одном стоит `SSD`, а на втором `HDD` с 5400 оборотами ил вообще битыми секторами, и до сетевых карт - у меня так игровая сетевая карта с заявленной скоростью в 1Гбит встроенная в мат.плату работала медленнее чем лысого года `D-Link` с заявленной скоростью в 100Мбит

Comment: На обоих новые SSD. Но это не важно, так как данные страниц пишутся  в оперативную память и сохраняются на диск блоками по 1000 страниц и это занимает меньше секунды, а парсинг - 30 и 120 секунд соответственно.

Comment: Ну попробуйте логировать все действия в парсере. И смотрите тайминг. Может будет понятно, что именно занимает много времени. Можно профайлером каким-то ещё пройтись, он тоже покажет, где код много ресурсов ест.